# Update unit price in a Custom Object Inventory__c from Pricebookentry unit price

Tags: apex

**Code**

```
public void updateprice()
     {
     List<Inventory__c> obj=[select Id, name,Product_Code__c,Remaining_Balance__c,unit_price__C from Inventory__c limit:10 ];
    for(Inventory__c i: obj)
     {
    PricebookEntry pe=[select UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id ='01s28000000DbRn' and Productcode=:i.Product_code__c];
    i.unit_price__c=pe.unitprice;
    }
    update obj;
    }
```

But it is showing exception as below,

> No rows to assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void updateList()
{ List<Inventory__c> lstobj;
   lstobj=[select Id, name,Product_Code__c,Remaining_Balance__c,unit_price__C from Inventory__c  ];
  for(Inventory__c i :lstobj)
  {

Map<Id,PricebookEntry> mapPe=new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>([select id, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id ='01s28000000DbRn' and Productcode = : i.Product_code__c]);
  for(Id id : mapPe.keySet())
    {  
       price=mapPe.get(id).unitprice;

 i.unit_price__c=price;
 }
}
   update lstobj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not the standard way to query inside loop.
Second thing is query results must be taken into list/map instead of object to avoid exceptions,

**Below might give exception if no records exist**

```
PricebookEntry pe=[select UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id ='01s28000000DbRn' and Productcode=:i.Product_code__c];
```

**Wont give exception**

```
List<PricebookEntry> pe=[select UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id ='01s28000000DbRn' and Productcode=:i.Product_code__c];
```

**Update Code** - As you required respective product code's PricebookEntry unit price field value to update, i used map.

```
public void updateprice()
{
   List<Inventory__c> obj=new List<Inventory__c>();
   Set<string> setProcode = set<String>();
   lstobj=[select Id, name,Product_Code__c,Remaining_Balance__c,unit_price__C from Inventory__c limit:10 ];
   for(Inventory__c i :lstobj){
      setProcode.add(Product_code__c);
   }
   Map<Id,PricebookEntry> mapPe=new Map<Id,PricebookEntry>();
   for(PricebookEntry pe: [select UnitPrice from PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id ='01s28000000DbRn' and Productcode in :setProcode]){
       mapPe.put(Productcode,pe);
   }

   for(Inventory__c i: lstobj)
   {
       if(i.Productcode !=null && mapPe.keyset().contains(i.Productcode)){
             i.unit_price__c=mapPe.get(i.Productcode).unitprice;
       }
   }

   update lstobj;
}
```

Comment: It still not updating inventory unit_price__c ,listpe is not retreiving any row .I want to update  inventory unit_price__c of same product in inventory by using standard unit price field for which Listpe query should retreive  record of the same product of which unit_price__c field is to be  updated.

Comment: It would have been better if you had given this explanation in Question itself